# Разные действия при изменении в двух диапазонах столбцов

Tags: excel, vba

Помогите пожалуйста: Имеется следующий макрос:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
Dim objCell As Range
With Target 
    If .Column < 1 Or .Column > 5 Or .Row < 1 Or .Row
> 100000000 Then
        Exit Sub
End With
For Each objCell In Target
    If TypeName(objCell.Value) = "String" Then
        objCell.Value = Left(objCell.Value, 10)  End If
Next End Sub
```

Он реагирует на изменение в ячейках диапазона <1 или >5. И призначении больше 10 - режет  значение до 10. Каким образом мне добавить данную проверку на нескольких столбцах?
Т. е. нужно что то вроде:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim objCell As Range
With Target
If .Column < 1 Or .Column > 5 Or .Row < 1 Or .Row > 100000000 Then
Exit Sub
End With
For Each objCell In Target
If TypeName(objCell.Value) = "String" Then
objCell.Value = Left(objCell.Value, 10)
End If

With Target
If .Column < 7 Or .Column > 9 Or .Row < 1 Or .Row > 100000000 Then
Exit Sub
End With
For Each objCell In Target
If TypeName(objCell.Value) = "String" Then
objCell.Value = Left(objCell.Value, 4)
End If

Next End Sub
```

Но при этом ругается. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: http://forum.msexcel.ru/index.php/topic,11512.0.html  Вместо того, чтобы показать нормальный пример, Вы начали бегать по сети?

Comment: А чем мой пример - не нормален?

Comment: Я ничего особо не хотел - только показать, как объединить 2 ограничения.

Comment: Встречный вопрос: чем мой код ненормален? Он объединяет два ограничения. Если не работает - была просьба показать в файле.

Comment: Возможно, подразумевается что-то другое, не событие на изменение в диапазоне изменяемых ячеек? Вопрос об объединении двух условий, это и показано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код подразумевает, что проводились изменения в диапазоне ячеек одного столбца.

Где Вы видели столбец или строку с номером меньше 1? :)
Зачем указывать ограничение на строку ниже миллионной?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim objCell As Range
    With Target
        If .Column > 9 Then Exit Sub

        For Each objCell In Target
            If TypeName(objCell.Value) = "String" Then
                If .Column < 6 Then
                    objCell.Value = Left(objCell.Value, 10)
                Else
                    objCell.Value = Left(objCell.Value, 4)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Для исключения ошибки при обработке значения нужно добавить проверку на длину значения.

Нужно отключать-включать события *EnableEvents*. На работоспособность в данном случае не влияет (но ячейки пересматриваются по  несколько раз, что тоже нехорошо), но в других случаях возможен выход в бесконечный цикл.

Если использовать дополнительную переменную, можно уйти от сравнения в цикле и тем самым ускорить работу:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim objCell As Range
Dim lClmn As Long
    With Target
        If .Column > 9 Or .Row > 100000000 Then Exit Sub
        If .Column < 6 Then lClmn = 10 Else: lClmn = 4
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each objCell In Target
        If Len(objCell.Value) > lClmn Then
            If TypeName(objCell.Value) = "String" Then
                objCell.Value = Left(objCell.Value, lClmn)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Вместо *If .Column > 9 Then Exit Sub* Ограничение на столбцы можно наложить так:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:I"), Target) Is Nothing Then
...
End If
```

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim objCell As Range
    With Target
        If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:H"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        For Each objCell In Target
            If TypeName(objCell.Value) = "String" Then
                If .Column = 2 Then
                    bjCell.Value = Left(objCell.Value, 10)
                Else
                    bjCell.Value = Left(objCell.Value, 4)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub Так не работает

Comment: Опять Ваш код не сработал.

Comment: Вставил код в модуль листа - у меня работает. Еще раз: покажите в своей теме ФАЙЛ-ПРИМЕР с ошибкой. Или все вместо Вас делать (в том числе и ошибку придумывать)?

Comment: За меня делать ничего не надо. Я попросил пример двух функций в примере и всё. Ошибка та, что ничего не работает как надо - не делает нужные ограничения - не отрезает строку до определённого количества.

Comment: Я добавил test.xls и в макросе добавил Ваш код.

Comment: wrong number of argument or invalid property assiend сейчас выходит при попытки использования вашего макроса.

Comment: Добавил обход ошибки при пустой ячейке. Код работает, проверено. Вашего файла не вижу, поэтому не могу сказать, что у Вас неправильно.

Comment: Не работает как надо. Проверил сначало - первые 2 столбца проверяет на 4 и всё проверка не работает дальше

Comment: Вы ничего раньше об этом не писали. Код подразумевает, что проводились изменения в диапазоне ячеек одного столбца и нужно было разграничить диапазоны столбцов..  По этому вопросу ответ дан полностью.

Comment: Вначале самом писал.

Comment: С первго по н-ный столбец до определённого ограничить с н-ного по - м-ный до другого значения.

Comment: В самом начале - просьба разделить диапазоны столбцов. Нет никакой информации о том, при каких условиях происходит обработка. По коду видно, что обрабатываться должен диапазон изменяемых ячеек одного столбца. Это  реализовано. Изменяете одну ячейку или диапазон (в одном столбце) - значение обрезается до нужной длины.  Если нужно не это, создайте новый вопрос, опишите подробно проблему. Тут и так уже в комментариях больше понаписано, чем в ответе

Comment: Я вроде с самого сначала на русском писал, что мне требуется. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, Ваш код должен ругаться на отсутствие `Next` для завершения первого блока `For`. Во-вторых, воспользуйтесь конструкцией `If ... Then ... ElseIf ...Then ... End If`. В Вашем случае должно получиться что-то вроде

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim objCell As Range
    With Target
        If .Column < 5 And .Row < 100000000 Then
            For Each objCell In Target
                If TypeName(objCell.Value) = "String" Then
                    objCell.Value = Left(objCell.Value, 10)
                End If
            Next objCell
        ElseIf .Column > 7 And .Column < 9 And .Row < 100000000 Then
            For Each objCell In Target
                If TypeName(objCell.Value) = "String" Then
                    objCell.Value = Left(objCell.Value, 4)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```